# BITS IIS Server Extension on Windows 10

Tags: iis, bit

How to install `BITS IIS Server Extension` on Windows 10?
I can't find anything about windows 10, everything is only about windows servers or is BITS IIS Server Extension not available for windows 10

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/iis-requirements-for-bits-uploads There is no clear documentation, but in general BITS is a Windows Server only feature, so not available on desktop Windows releases.

Comment: It is impossible to installa BITS IIS Server Extension on Windows 10, you can only install it on Web Server. For more detailed information, you can refer to this link: [https://www.netiq.com/documentation/appmanager-9/installationguide/data/b10rrbse.html](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/appmanager-9/installationguide/data/b10rrbse.html).